# Time-based thread-safe priority queue

Tags: java, scala, data-structures, scheduling

I need some queue-like datastracture for the following task:

1. Some thread adds data items with attached delay value (for example in seconds), e.g. `queue.add(data, delay)`.
2. There can be different delays as well as identical and queue should act as a priority queue：smaller delay item is closer to the end (gets dequeued faster)
3. Every second `delay` of the queued items should decrease by 1 until it reaches 0 (then it will be left unchanged as 0)
4. Amongst the items where `delay` is `0` the order of dequeuing is just their order of insertion (though the order of reaching `0` is better)
5. Some client threads systematically get the elements from this queue, and it gives only the `delay = 0` element. If none such exists, then it blocks, or throws.

Thus, I want some functionality of queue + a little scheduling, threadsafe. I suspect that this type of thing should be quite a regular task in some contexts.

**My question**: is there any production ready solution for `java` or `scala` for this type of task? I'd like not to reinvent another bicycle.

**EDIT**: it seems that there are exact such thing in *java* standard library: `DelayQueue`, take a look at it before following answers.

Comment: Instead of modifying the `delay` of all items every second it is better to store the time stamp when they are ready to be dequeued. The order of the queue does not change by that and the update effort can be spared.

Comment: @Henry That's reasonable indeed.

Comment: Did you look at ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: It sounds like you should really be using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor as this wraps both a delaying PriorityQueue and a ThreadPool in one.

Comment: Actually, one could add a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor as an intermediate step; when reaching the delay = 0, it will add it to another queue where it will be immediately available for polling; but then you need a second queue anyway (but not necessarily a PriorityQueue this time).

Comment: @MattTimmermans In my case I'd like to have a fixed number of client threads, which process the queue, so ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor seems to be not fully compliant with my goal. But thanks for info, it is useful to know for future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a `PriorityQueue` that should take as input `Comparable` objects.
You should compare these objects based on a `Timestamp` field (the smaller the better); as already mentioned by @Henry it would be better to store a `Timestamp` rather than a `delay`. This is very easy to implement; just store `currentTime + delay`.

Then, when a client requests for the head element, you need to create a `synchronized` method that does the following operations:

- first `peek()` to check if the head element has a `timestamp < currentTime`
- if yes, `poll()` this element, else throw.

---

2nd solution (ported from my comment):

Actually, one could add a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor as an intermediate layer;
Now you don't need a `Timestamp`, just provide the `delay` to the executor.

When each `runnable/callable` executes, the corresponding object is added to another normal FIFO Queue where it will be immediately available for polling;

Your clients may now poll elements from this second FIFO Queue.

Comment: Used your initial suggestion and it was indeed trivial. Thanks.